# errors of non-consistent worker and driver python versions on databricks clusters

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, databricks, azure-databricks

I am running Python3 code on databricks clusters from Eclipse on MacBook.

When I run:

```
 spark = SparkSession.builder \
 .master("local") \
 .appName("Word Count") \
 .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
 .getOrCreate()

 spark.createDataFrame(df_data) # df_data is a pandas dataframe,
```

I got error:

```
 Exception: Python in worker has different version 3.6 than that in driver 3.5, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

In my eclipse:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON = pytohn3
PYSPARK_PYTHON = /Users/a_name/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/bin/python
```

So, I would like to check the python versions of driver and worker of the databricks cluster from databricks notebook.

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

I got:

```
3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| [GCC 7.2.0]

import subprocess
python_version = subprocess.check_output(['python', '--version'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print(python_version)
```

I got:

```
b'Python 2.7.15 :: Anaconda, Inc.\n'
```

I do not know why there are two python versions here ? 
I should change the python version of my python code in Eclipse ?

Comment: A question: you added `PYSPARK_PYTHON = pytohn3` -- is this a typo only in the comment or that's actually wrong in your system? Also, does it work in the command line? (if it does, you may want to make sure that your launch in Eclipse uses the same environment variables).

Answer (score 0):

It's OK for two Python versions, because the two codes for checking the Python version are invoking different Python of your environment, as below.

1. The Python version returned from the `sys.version` code comes from your current working Python interpreter.
2. But the Python version returned from the `subprocess.check_output(['python', '--version'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` code is from the default Python version of your current OS session.

So they are differnt normally, please see the description of [`sys.version`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#sys.version) and [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) of Python 3.6.

And as the issue `Exception: Python in worker has different version 3.6 than that in driver 3.5, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.` said, your current PySpark driver need a Python 3.5 runtime, so try to install another Python 3.5 runtime in your environment, and you can fix it via the code below without only configure `PYSPARK_PYTHON` variable.

```
# Ofcourse, I know you are working on MacOS, the value for Linux is just a sample.
import os
os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"]="<the path of Python 3.5 runtime, such as /usr/bin/python3.5 on Linux>"
```